# Colorbox Not Working Properly When Invoked From Within jQuery Slide

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I've incorporated the Awkward Showcase content slider into my website and on one of the slides have an anchored image which when clicked should invoke colorbox to open a youtube video in its own dialog.  Without using the slider colorbox works great.  Once the slider is applied colorbox no longer works. I thought immediately that it had to with the slide not be the first to load and maybe colorbox can't apply itself to the node, even though it isn't hidden.  So I used Awkards custom function parameter to invoke colorbox on slide change.  Now the colorbox dialog's background (diagonal lines) shows up but no dialog box... if you scroll down the page you get a white blob that might be the colorbox dialog but no content within it.  Any ideas why this is happening?  Something to do with how the slides are loaded.

I took out the code, made a separate page to test and see if I could figure it out here's the code http://pastebin.com/WSzWCGSg and the plugin urls are below.  The test piece has colorbox working on the first slide then not working on any subsequent slides or the original after the slider is moved.

Awkward Showcase - http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/
Colorbox - jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: You should probably post your code.

Comment: Thanks Colin, sorry I've now added a test page to the original post with what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had tried to invoke colorbox using its custom_function: arg by simply putting in the colorbox code. But you have to encapsulate it in a function(){} otherwise it doesn't work.

so using the code snippet I changed the custom_function:

```
function() { jQuery(".videos_colorbox").colorbox({iframe:true, 
                                                  innerWidth:640, 
                                                  innerHeight:390});}
```

instead of using just custom_function:

```
jQuery(".videos_colorbox").colorbox({iframe:true, 
                                     innerWidth:640, 
                                     innerHeight:390})
```

which definitely does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your slide show is dynamic but I would bind the even as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#CLOSEST_ID_TO_CONTAINER_THAT_HOLDS_ALL_SLIDES').on('click','.YOUR_ANCHOR_CLASS',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).colorbox({...});
    });
});
```

Without seeing what you are doing though makes this answer a stab in the dark.